# How to access elements of an array of an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class arrayOfArrays{ 
       public Object[] array1;
       public int size;           

       arrayOfArrays(){
            array1 = new Object[10];
            array1[0] = new arrayOfInts();
   }
}

class arrayOfInts{
      public Integer[] array2;
      public int size;

      arrayOfInts(){
         array2 = new Integer[10]; 
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a 2d array of some sort that has varying length of the arrays that are contained within it. For example, array1[0] will have an array of Ints that has a length of 3. array1[1] will have an array of Ints of length 5. and so on.

If I want to access elements of array2 from within my arrayOfArrays class. How would I accomplish that?

I have tried: array1[this.size].array2[size] = x;
However, this gives me an error. Do I need to cast the second array? Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Please correct the above code, this will never compile.

Comment: You could achieve what you are trying to do with ragged arrays. In Java you have only to specify the outer most dimension of an array when defining the array. In your code, it would look something like this: `int[][] myArray = new int[10][]; myArray[0] = new int[3]; myArray[1] = new int[5]; myArray[2] = new int[1]; ...`. You can get the length of each `int[]` by accessing it and reading the `length` attribute: `myArray[0].length` will yield `5`, `myArray[1].length` will yield `3` and so on.

Comment: @Turing85 Right. That was just out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you creates those classes.

You can simply store any kind of things in an Object array.

```
Object[] array1 = new Object[ 5 ];
Random rd = new Random();

for( int i = 0; i<5; i++ )
  array1[ i ] = new int[ rd.nextInt( 5 ) + 1 ];

System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString( array1 ) );
```

Here i've created 5 int array with random size.

The problem is that you have to cast the result of array1[i] into an int[] as far as you define it as an Object[]

```
int[] o1 = ( int[] ) array1[ 1 ];
System.out.println( o1 );
```

A simpler solution would probably be to use a list on Integer arrays. This way there is non needs to cast.

```
List<Integer[]> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

for( int i = 0; i<5; i++ )
  list1.add( new Integer[ rd.nextInt( 5 ) + 1 ] );

for( Integer[] array : list1 )
  for( int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    array[i] = rd.nextInt( 100 );

System.out.println(  Arrays.deepToString( list1.toArray() ) );
```